# Need code for template file to generate html file with different title and html file name based on user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to generate a template html file, based on variable name (which will be changing dynamically based on user input) the title and some other variable names will be replaced from user input. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you have an application, from which you are taking inputs from users to create an HTML template.

You can use javascript string literals

```
createHTMLTemplate(userInput){
return `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>${userInput.title}</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="background-color: red;">Hello World!</h1>
<p>${userInput.anyothervariable}</p>

</body>
</html>
`
}
```

Comment: I need to create new html file also from this Template and filename of this new html file should be user input name.

Comment: you can use the fs module and create the file and write the string to it.
`
fs.writeFile(userInput.filename, createHTMLTemplate(userInput))
.then(() => {
//action on sucess
})
`
More about fs module
[link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.htm)